# Runtime Memory management of RAM in c++

Tags: c++, memory, binaryfiles

We have created one application in that it takes lots of memory for storing the results in RAM. I need to optimize memory usage but storing and accessing the data should not take more time. So we have decided to use a Binary file for storing that data. Is that any other method for RAM optimization?
example: vector[100] in that each index having separate data. At a time I need to access the data individually.

Comment: `optimize memory usage but storing and accessing the data should not take more time` these two goals are commonly contradictory. May be you do not use the right data structures to store your value but without any detail we cannot help you. Do you need to load all the data in memory ?

Comment: I don't want to store all the information once. consider we are having list of 100 values in that each time based on the index each value has to retrieve the data.